# Comparing with more than one char in C++

Tags: c++, char

Say I have an input that is stored in a `char c`, and in a conditional I need to check whether it is either of two different characters, for example `'n'` and `'N'`. It's obvious that I can make a conditional with a logical `OR` operator:

```
if(c == 'n' || c == 'N')
...
```

However, if there are significantly more than just two conditions, than that will require significantly more logical operators to be used, and it will become tedious to write, look at, and edit. Is there a way to condense this process? To make it look like something along the lines of this:

```
if(c == '[N][n]')
...
```

Does anything of the sort exist?

Comment: You could have a set and test for membership.

Comment: Look into the `std::string::find_any_*` functions.

Comment: `if(c = 'n' || c = 'N')` --> `if(c == 'n' || c == 'N')`

Comment: Perhaps using a suitable container and [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: `tolower(whatever) == 'lowercase_letter'`

Comment: Aditi Rawat good catch, I fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a string of your matching characters and see if the character in question exists in the string:

```
char c;
std::string good_chars = "nNyYq";
if(good_chars.find(c) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "it's good!";
}
```

Comment: An O(N) solution to an O(1) problem. Are you in the hardware leasing business?

Comment: @Bathsheba `O(n)`? What's `n` in this case to you? It looks to me like everything is constant...

Comment: find is an O(N) traversal.

Comment: @Bathsheba I suppose that if you're talking about my solution to the problem "Find if a character is in the set of N good characters" you'd be right that it's `O(n)`, but once he implements this, that `n` is a constant (unless the set of good chars is changing at runtime, but that's not specified). Remember that even `for(int i=0; i < 999999; i++) { }` is O(1)...

Answer (score 5):

A low-tech solution would be to use a `switch` statement instead. Reading and editing may turn out to be much easier with `case` labels if you have a lot of matching characters.

```
bool matches(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A more advanced solution would be to store the characters in a container. `std::set` would be an option:

```
bool matches(char c)
{
    // note: might want to use static storage for `chars`
    std::set<char> const chars =
    {
        'n',
        'N',
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
    };
    return chars.find(c) != end(chars);
}
```

`std::string` allows for a more condensed form, which may be good or bad as far as readability and maintainability is concerned:

```
bool matches(char c)
{
    // note: might want to use static storage for `chars`
    std::string const chars = "nNabc";
    return chars.find(c) != std::string::npos;
}
```

Note that different containers have different algorithmic complexity characteristics, which may be relevant if a function like `match` should actually turn out to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: You ought to note that, in order of your presentation, the approaches are O(1), O(log N), then O(N).

Comment: Is a switch really O(1)? I'd expect the worst case to still be an O(n) test until you match

Comment: @Bathsheba: I'm not sure if that's not bordering on premature optimisation. The OP's question was mainly about code becoming *"tedious to write, look at, and edit"*. However, I'll add a note about the container choice having an impact on algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_upper` `or to_lower` APIs if your scanning is not case sensitive this way:

```
char c = 'n';
if( static_cast<unsigned char>('N') == std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) )
    // do something
```

Or:

```
char c = 'n';
if( static_cast<unsigned char>('n') == std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) )
    // Do something
```

Comment: These two functions practically require you to cast the argument to `unsigned char`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper for more details.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Edited now.

Comment: Why a C-style cast and not `static_cast<unsigned char>`? Anyway, that no longer really justifies a downvote, so I'll remove it.